# How does Chinese input work once it's installed? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, input-language, input-method, chinese

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to install simplified Chinese input and I think I've installed it correctly- I can change the keyboard input to Chinese, and when I do that, Chinese characters pop out.

However, either there is something buggy about this input method, or I'm not using it right, because for example when I try to type "lao" (as in "laoshi"), I get:

拉o

Any advice?

Comment: You need to understand the input method that is used. Probably you are not doing the entry correctly. I can't say for Chinese, but in Japanese if you type only part of the alpha letters for a character, this might happen (for example entering "kami" would be かみ but entering "kam" would be かm).

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly the same problem as I had when I used iBus Pinyin. In my opinion it must be a bug of the program. (This version of iBus does not work any more.) The program (IME) erroneously only accepts 2 keystrokes per character, and when pinyin (commonly) requires more than 2 keystrokes per character, the remaining keystrokes, in your case the "o" will go into forming other characters.

I switched to sunpinyin, which also comes with iBus. That seems to have solved it for me.

[fcitx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818089/how-to-install-chinese-input-in-english-ubuntu) is also recommended, I read.